# HTTP Attribute Same as Routing - ASP.Net Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I am making an ASP.net core 2.0 Web API and have a method in my controller called

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
public void Create()
{
    //  var d = employee;
}
```

Does the `HttpPost` act as the same the `[Route]` attribute or do I need both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Asp.Net Core Web API you do not need both.

It acts the same as `Route` and is the advised approach. When using MVC with views you use `Route` and `Http{Verb}` together.

Documentation states...

> When building a REST API, it's rare that you will want to use `[Route(...)]` on an action method. It's better to use the more specific `Http*Verb*Attributes` to be precise about what your API supports. Clients of REST APIs are expected to know what paths and HTTP verbs map to specific logical operations.

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

I would also advise having your actions return `IActionResult` to allow the proper HTTP Verb to be returned from the action.

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
public IActionResult Create() {
    //  var d = employee;
    return Ok();
}
```

`void` actions always return `200 OK` unless an exception is thrown. This limits the possible response from the action.

Comment: For the OP - this is very opinion based. we have a SPA with .net webapi, return our custom interface from everything, and use both [route()] and [HttpVerb] attributes. works a treat.

Comment: Yes of course I will return IActionResult at the very least but when testing sometimes just easier to write void :). I think I will try to stick to what is recommended. I think this is more convention based vs functionality, that's what I asked the question as it seemed like both pretty much could achieve what is needed.

Comment: @chobo2 Yes. they basically achieve the same thing and the documentation is more of a recommendation than a hard and fast rule. Even in their wording they use *rare* and *not shouldn't* or *don't*

Comment: "When using MVC with views you use Route and Http{Verb} together.", I haven't worked on any MVC application where I applied this, at all. I find it a waste of my time to write two attributes when I need one

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it is something that came over from the previous version. They both work either way. :)